# C - what does while(*Table[i]) mean/do?

Tags: c, arrays, string, while-loop

I need to add a string to an array and need some help figuring out what this means. Here is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int insert(char *word, char *Table[], int n)
{
//*word is the string to be added, *Table[] is the array, n is
//the return value, which is the number of words in the array after adding *word
    int i = 0;
    while(*Table[i])
    {
        if strcmp(*Table[i], *word) == 0)
        {
            return n;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote this awhile ago and am just now revisiting it. I have no idea what while *Table[i] means, therefore I have no idea what the code that follows means. Also, this code is incomplete so don't bother telling me it won't add the string.

Answer (score 1):

The * operator dereferences a pointer, and so does the [i].

Since Table is declared as char *Table[] this is the same as char ** in that it is a pointer to a pointer type (like a 2 dimensional array).

In this case it is apparent from the usage that Table is an array of strings (a string being an array of char (hence the array of arrays type)).

So Table[i] is a pointer to the i-th string in the array of strings, and then the * dereferences this again. What the author is doing here is looking for a NULL (zero) which follows the array of strings, which is clearly the method of determining the end of the array.